# How to get all the svg object under an area in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg

I'm making a svg drawing app. I have a tool that allows the user to select all the shapes in a rectangular area.

I need a way to detect the svg shapes under the rectangle.

I tried to use "document.elementFromPoint" and "getIntersectionList" on my root svg element.  I use a path svg object with the fillColor set to none to display a line. getIntersectionList selects the path if the area is over the invisible region, so it isn't working. "document.elementFromPoint" doesn't work if I scroll.

The only way I can think of is to generate a click event on all the pixels inside the area, and listen to that event.

How can I do that? thank you

edit:
Here's an illustration. The white square is the selection area. Items under it must be highlighted in red. The square follows the mouse. If I move the mouse away from the lines, they must turn back white
[image: description of the selection]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a click events on the svg elements, I would strongly suggest checking [ngx-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-svg) library. It provides various svg elements and events on each of them. The usage is also pretty simple -

```
<svg-container id="test-container>
  <svg-circle radius="2" (clickEvent)="doSomething($event)"></svg-circle>
</svg-container>
```

The events are available on all elements. Also you can customize different stuff using the library. For more information, check the documentation of the library.

Comment: I need to simulate an "area click". I need all the pixels in a rectangular area to simulate being clicked.
I need to call doSomething if the mouse isn't exactly on the object, but the rectangle is

Comment: Could you attach screens and more detailed explanation of what you would like to achieve, since currently your description is vague and hard to understand.

Comment: https://ibb.co/FHfz2G4
The white square is the selection area. All items under it must be highlighted in red. The square must follow the mouse, so that if I move it away from the lines, the lines turn back white